# Trouble implementing data source methods for UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

I want load a plist file and use the data of plist to init a TableView.

When I use:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.data count];
}
```

but`[self.data count]`always 0.NSLog could output correct data.

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"supportList" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *data =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

And plist source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>First</string>
    <string>Second</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please use the datasource methods of UITableView class

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.data count];
}
```

And don't forget to set the tableview's datasource.

```
chosentableView.datasource = self;
```

Comment: But I set a NSLog after     `NSLog(@"%@",data);` ,like ` NSLog(@"data count:%lu",(unsigned long)[self.data count]);`  the output is `currencyTransform[13493:1851617] data count:0`

Comment: Can you put a NSlog on the plistPath to check the path right or not?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",plistPath) like this？

Comment: YES, and you can post the path.

Comment: OK , I will try it later on. Thanks

Comment: I check the plist path,it's right!And `NSLog(@"%@",data);` also right.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the `uitableview` class by default methods,
And connect `dataSource` of tableview by `code/xib/storyboard`.
change you code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.data.count;
}
```

Comment: yeah！But I have a new bug,the data count always 0.

Comment: If data count always 0 then empty cell is showing , or you can print nslog before return statement. if it is print then add some data in array.

Comment: You must check the plist code , That is working or not.